# CSS transition not when child is selected

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-transitions

I've got a side navigation with the items flying out when they are hovered. Now I've added a second level to the navigation. The problem is that the `li a` with sub-items fly only out when a sub-link is hovered.

**Possible scenarios:**

1. Parent with child hovered: parent flies out
2. Child hovered: child flies out (but not parent)
3. Parent without child hovered: parent flies out

Here is a JSBin of what I mean:
http://jsbin.com/zusoyeweqa/edit?html,css,js,output

How can I have only the list-element selected fly transitioned?

This is the **HTML**:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" role="navigation">
   <ul class="side-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Link 2</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the **CSS**

```
#site-navigation ul>li{
   font-size: 1.6em;
   width: auto;
   float: right;
   display: block;
   clear: both;
   line-height: 1em;
   margin-bottom: 1px;
}

#site-navigation ul>li a{
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

   font-family: "Oswald",Arial,sans-serif;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   background: #FFF;
   color: #000;
   padding: .25em;
   width: auto;
}

#site-navigation ul>li a:hover{
   background: #c00;
   color: #fff;
   padding-right: 1em;
}

#site-navigation ul>li>ul>li a {
  color: #FFF;
  background: none;
}
```

EDIT: Added a jsbin http://jsbin.com/zusoyeweqa/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: can you create a demo that shows the issue youre having? (jsfiddle/codepen/etc)

Comment: target the first level more specifically, something like http://jsfiddle.net/0jg8ua09/ ? or http://jsfiddle.net/0jg8ua09/1/ ? I am not sure what you mean by fly out

Comment: Just did, here it is http://jsbin.com/zusoyeweqa/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I don't think you can do that with CSS only since you want something to happen to the parent when something is happening to the child. There is no parent selector yet in CSS so you will need js to achieve this. If you are accepting js answers, please tag the question with the javascript or jquery tag depending on your technology

Comment: I want the parent to not fly out when the child flies out.

Comment: @Hedge yes exactly you want a specific behaviour to occur on the parent based on the child which is not possible with CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps ..

replace yous css with following

```
#site-navigation .side-nav>li{
   font-size: 1.6em;
   width: auto;
   float: right;
   display: block;
   clear: both;
   line-height: 1em;
   margin-bottom: 1px;
}

#site-navigation .side-nav>li a{
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

   font-family: "Oswald",Arial,sans-serif;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   background: #FFF;
   color: #000;
   padding: .25em;
   width: auto;
  position:relative;
}
#site-navigation ul>li a:hover{
   background: #c00;
   color: #fff;
   right: 1em;
}
#site-navigation ul>li a:hover .{
   background: #c00;
   color: #fff;
   right: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use position relative and right to fly only the selected item out.

```
#site-navigation .side-nav>li{
   font-size: 1.6em;
   width: auto;
   float: right;
   display: block;
   clear: both;
   line-height: 1em;
   margin-bottom: 1px;
}

#site-navigation .side-nav>li a{
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

   font-family: "Oswald",Arial,sans-serif;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   background: #FFF;
   color: #000;
   padding: .25em;
   width: auto;
   /* Use position relative and right to fly out.  */
   position: relative;
   right: 0;
}

#site-navigation ul>li a:hover{
   background: #c00;
   color: #fff;
   /* Use right to fly out. */
   right: 1em;
}
```